# How to create a stormpath user without email?

Tags: stormpath

Some users of my application do not have an email. I want them to register under a tenant. I couldn't find a way to make email field as non-mandatory while registration. The basic requirement of a stormpath account is an email and password.

Comment: email and password are always required in Stormpath

Comment: There are some hacky ways to get around this -- for instance, you can remove the email field from the registration page, and fill that in with a dummy value on your server before sending the request off to Stormpath.

Answer (score 3):

Stormpath currently always requires a user's email AND password to create an account. In the future, we plan to remove this limitation.

For now, the only way to get around this is to fill in a dummy email address. Sorry!